# How to insert a record in a table so that the string field with id?

Tags: sql, t-sql

I have a table to be imported from excel.It has an column called the sector table name "ExcelTable"

```
  Name  Title   Sector
  John  manager Sofware 
  Sam   Lawyer   Jus
```

"ExcelTable" has 3284 rows.I create table called "SECTORS"."SECTORS" table's cloumn like this

```
SectorId SectorName
  1       Sofware
  2        Jus
```

It has 61 rows.

I inserted "EXCELTABLE" to "GLOBALCONTACTS".They has same rows number 3284 I want to insert "GLOBAL_CONTACTS" table sector by sectorid .It is now

```
 ContactId   Name  Title  Sector 
      1       John  manager null 
      2       Sam   Lawyer   null
```

I want it to be like this

```
ContactId   Name  Title  Sector 
    1       John  manager   1
    2       Sam   Lawyer    2
```

Comment: can you provide more information for sector

Comment: Does the data already exist in GLOBAL_CONTACTS, or are we inserting fresh data into it? Where does `ContactId` come from?

Comment: I inserted "EXCELTABLE" to "GLOBAL_CONTACTS"."GLOBAL_CONTACTS" has contacid.It is identity column."EXCELTABLE" hasnt identity columnn like contactid.because I imported it from excel but contains the same number of records in two tables.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you just want to join `ExcelTable` to `Sectors` for an `INSERT`:

```
INSERT INTO GLOBAL_CONTACTS (Name,Title,Sector)
SELECT e.Name,e.Title,s.SectorID
FROM ExcelTable e
INNER JOIN Sectors s
ON e.Sector = s.SectorName
```